# How do I dynamically resize the whole center div and all of its content?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I'm trying to make the center blue div expand until it touches an edge of a screen. I would like it to expand the font size of all subtexts and the size of the discord iframe embed so that it is relatively the same size on any device. I'm not sure if this is even possible without javascript.

you can see the site at https://duelcraft.games/

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 64px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  border-style: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font: normal 16px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  background-position: top;
  height: 100%;
}

.test {
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #9FE7FF;
}

.email-part {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--(c) 2022 DuelCraft-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DuelCraft</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/icon.png">

</head>

<body background='images/background.png'>
  <div class="test">
    <h1>DuelCraft</h1>
    <p class="main">DuelCraft Minecraft Server</p>
    <h2>How do I join?</h2>
    <p>Connect to play.duelcraft.games</p>
    <div align="center"><iframe src="https://discord.com/widget?id=995858337293926400&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe></div>
    <div class="email-part">
      <p>Email user@example.com for help!</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <p> ©2022 DuelCraft </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can I ask you for more info? do you want something like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTAD3.jpg , if no can you tell me some details, thanks :)

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas I want it to expand without losing the aspect ratio of the blue box.

Comment: so you want that in mobile version, the scrollbar doesn't appear https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX06X.jpg and it automatically became the same aspect-ratio resizing itself (with less height, but 100% width)? is correct? or I am wrong?

Comment: so it seems that different phones have different problems, my phone tends to undersize the thing. https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/995858337293926403/998978855232610374/IMG_3791.png

Comment: ok. I get the problem! is in head tag

Comment: added a answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your last comment,
I know the solution.

add this to your HTML `<head>` element.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

[image]

> this makes the website responsive for mobile versions.
>
>  this code is automatically generated in most of the IDEs (like vscode)
>
>  but in your case, there isn't so just add it

2. also for not having the margin on top and bottom, 
   use `margin: 0` to the `<body>` selector
3. adding a small space in every part (top, left, right) is by adding this code:

> the trick there is [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  .test {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

[image]

> in this photo I added a padding of 1rem (~16px), 
> if you want less padding, just change the value

> I used a `@media` because we want that: the code we will use works only on mobile, so on the desktop will be centered, and on mobile there is padding.

4. for making the discord `iframe` responsive use `width:100%` so it will use the maximum space it can have from the parent div.

```css
  .test, iframe {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

> I wrote a comma here to avoid repeating the code multiple times.

[image]

5. for making the `<h1>` responsive we will use the `vw` unit in CSS.

```css
  h1 {
    font-size: 12vw;
  }
```

> `vw` is the **width_screen/100**

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 64px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  border-style: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font: normal 16px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  background-position: top;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.test {
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #9FE7FF;
}

.email-part {
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  .test,
  iframe {
    width: 100%;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 12vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--(c) 2022 DuelCraft-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DuelCraft</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/icon.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body background='images/background.png'>
  <div class="test">
    <h1>DuelCraft</h1>
    <p class="main">DuelCraft Minecraft Server</p>
    <h2>How do I join?</h2>
    <p>Connect to play.duelcraft.games</p>
    <div align="center"><iframe src="https://discord.com/widget?id=995858337293926400&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe></div>
    <div class="email-part">
      <p>Email support@duelcraft.games for help!</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <p> ©2022 DuelCraft </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have one problem with this, It seems to allocate a handful of pixels on the top and left sides of the aqua box. How do I turn this off?

Comment: @ICE_Plane ok let'see, 5 minutes

Comment: yes, add `margin: 0` to the body tag, edited the answer now. tell me if is working or not

Comment: `margin: 0` seems to fix the issue, is there a way I can get 10 pixels on all sides of the aqua box?

Comment: ok, let's see if we can solve also this

Comment: edited now, with the solution (if I help you like this answer and accept it) hope it helps :)

Comment: ok so that seems to add a nice little border it's just that the discord thing does not follow with it.

Comment: @ICE_Plane ok, solved this time. see the answer now (hope is helpful. if yes, please upvote the answer, I really answered all your questions)

Comment: I don't think anything has changed https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/995858337293926403/998994995866513490/IMG_3792.png?width=293&height=605

Comment: in my case is change https://i.stack.imgur.com/3henO.jpg, make sure you added `width: 100%` to the iframe. I tried to help you anyways

Comment: the percentage seems to work great! could you put that in the HTML and then I will accept it.

Comment: ok, in a style tag?

Comment: added in a style tag

Comment: oh, I was going to put it in the HTML but I get why you didn't I will accept your answer now

Comment: could you remove the style sheet from the HTML? it makes it kinda confusing.

Comment: ok, I thinked that you tell me do to it, now I will change it

Comment: changed now, see if is ok

Comment: It's good now! Thank you for all of the help!